# Python 3 code not working as I expected it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I was working on a simple python turtle module game when I encountered a problem. The game's point was for you(a red square) to dodge an obstacle(blue circle). Every time the blue circle reached the bottom of the screen it was supposed to reset to the top. When this comes to happen, the circle resets for a second then teleports back down again. Here is my code

```
#Import modules
import turtle
import time
import random

#Create window
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Street Raiders")
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.screensize(400, 400)

#Draw border
borderPen = turtle.Turtle()
borderPen.color("white")
borderPen.pensize(3)
borderPen.speed(0)
borderPen.penup()
borderPen.hideturtle()
borderPen.setposition(-100, -100)
borderPen.pendown()

for sides in range(4):
    borderPen.fd(200)
    borderPen.lt(90)

#Create player
playerCar = turtle.Turtle()
playerCar.speed(0)
playerCar.color("red")
playerCar.shape("square")
playerCar.setheading(90)
playerCar.penup()
playerCar.setposition(0, -75)
playerX = playerCar.xcor()

#Define player movement functions
def move_left():
    global playerX
    if playerX < -85 or playerX == -85:
        playerX = -75
        playerCar.setx(playerX)
    else:
        playerX -= 10
        playerCar.setx(playerX)

def move_right():
    global playerX
    if playerX > 85 or playerX == 85:
        playerX = 75
        playerCar.setx(playerX)
    else:
        playerX += 10
        playerCar.setx(playerX)
#Allow player movement
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

#Create obstacles
obstacleY = 75
obstacle = turtle.Turtle()
obstacle.speed(0)
obstacle.shape("circle")
obstacle.color("blue")
obstacle.penup()
obstacle.setposition(random.randint(-80, 81), obstacleY)

#Move obstacles
alive = True
while True:
    if alive:
        obstacle.sety(75)
        obstacle.setx(random.randint(-80, 81))
        for moves in range(30):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            obstacleY -= 5
            obstacle.sety(obstacleY)
else:
    print("GAME OVER... TRY AGAIN")
```

`

If you know why it is not working please respond. Thanks!

Comment: SO is a _terrible_ debugger. The best way to find out why it is not working is to debug it, since you have the code and know what you want to do with it. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the game loop, you are not resetting the value of the variable `obstacleY` to the top of the screen; instead you are temporarily setting the location of the obstacle there, then it resumes its course:

```
while True:
    if alive:
#         obstacle.sety(75)               # <-- replace this
        obstacleY = 75                    # <-- with that
        obstacle.setx(random.randint(-80, 81))
        for moves in range(30):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            obstacleY -= 5
            obstacle.sety(obstacleY)
else:
    print("GAME OVER... TRY AGAIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    if alive:
        obstacle.sety(75)
        obstacle.setx(random.randint(-80, 81))
        for moves in range(30):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            obstacleY -= 5
            obstacle.sety(obstacleY)
else:
    print("GAME OVER... TRY AGAIN")
```

SHOULD BE

```
while alive:
    obstacle.sety(75)
    obstacle.setx(random.randint(-80, 81))
    for moves in range(30):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        obstacleY -= 5
        obstacle.sety(obstacleY)
else:
    print("GAME OVER... TRY AGAIN")
```